# Nonlinear first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How to solve the differential equation $(dy/dx)^2 = (x-y)^2$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$?

I solved the equation by partitioning it into two differential equations.

1) $dy/dx = x-y $
The solution is —>   $1-x+y = -\exp(-x)$

and

2) $dy/dx = -(x-y)$
Solution —>  $1+x-y = \exp(x)$

How do we write combined solution of such equations.

Comment: How about $1\pm x\mp y=\pm\exp(\pm x)?$

Comment: To solve for $y$, note that $(\pm)\times(\pm)=+,$ and $(\pm)\times(\mp)=-.$

Comment: The answer may be exp(2x)|1-x+y| = |1+x-y|. Some mistakes may be there as it is one of four given options. But other options were also in this form. So basically answer should be in this form. But how do we get it?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+y=x \implies y=x-1+Ke^{-x}$$
Don't forget the constant of integration
$$y'-y=-x \implies y(x)=x+1+Ke^x$$

Comment: Constant for first equation is k= -1 and for second k= 1. Then where did the constants go? I forgot to mention initial condition is given y(0) = 0.

Comment: I see you just forgot inital conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Both distinct solutions are correct, as 
$$
y(x)=1+x-e^x=-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)
$$
and also
$$
y(x)=e^{-x}-(1-x)=\frac12x^2+O(x^3)
$$
have a horizontal tangent at the origin.

[image]

You get another two valid solutions if you switch at $x=0$ from one solution to the other.

Comment: What can be the combined form of both distinct solutions?

Comment: The upper solution for $x<0$ and the lower solution for $x\ge 0$ so that the graph around zero looks like $-\frac12x|x|$. And the other way around so that the piecewise combination is a monotonically increasing function.